# Updater for python from git repo

Tags: python, windows

I have a question. I am working on an application and am currently in the process of adding an update function, but how can I do this?

I have a repo on GitHub and want to download everything from it and overwrite files with changes. However, this is not so easy, especially in Windows.

I looked around a bit and found a module called PythonGit. And I can update my repo with `git.Repo.clone_from('git url', 'local dir')`, but how do I do that now, that this is executed from another file, and the current Python script is terminated. Because I can't overwrite anything that is currently open/used. So how can I make it so that I start another file that downloads and overwrites this and also terminates the current script?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This is a Python (and Windows) programming question. The only relationship it has to Git or GitHub is that this is where you're getting your new Python code: you'd have exactly the same problem if you were using https to download new code from AWS for instance. So just solve the Python issue, since you already know how to download a repository.

Comment: If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't have asked a question. And just because I know how to download a repo doesn't mean that solves my problem.

Comment: Right - I put the comment in because I was shifting the tags. I think you might want to refocus the text of the question as well.

Comment: You can create a batch (or VBS) file that will run your `updater.py` script while the main application is closed.